# Play Attacking my Husband

Tags: dogs, biting

My 5 month old mini schnauzer does not like cuddles. But, he does follow me through out the house. Outside he can be off lead in safe situations away from roads. He never runs more than 50 feet away from me and after exploring always comes back to me. He is just about housebroken.
My problem is with my husband and my pup’s relationship with him. My husband lets him out of his kennel and brings him for his morning walk on leash. Other than that he doesn’t really give him any attention. He is not a dog lover.
Recently, my pup is unrelenting in his playful ( at least I think they are) attacks on my husband. He jumps on the couch and immediately starts nipping and sometimes even barking at him. I’ve tried scolding him, giving him time outs and on the rare occasion where he sits next to my husband treats. Nothing has worked. Each day I end up taking the dog to a different floor with me. Then he behaves.
Help!

Comment: Welcome! Please add a clear question or an aim you want to reach. As your post is now it is not clear if you want to train your dog, to train your husband, to know if this is normal behaviour or anything else...

Comment: Without actually seeing and hearing *how exactly* your dog barks and nibs at your husband, it's impossible to say if this behavior is playful or aggressive. You should consider hiring a professional dog trainer who visits you at home, analyzes the dogs behavior and explains to you what you can do to improve it.